# Forwarding Class Messages

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, message-forwarding

I know that I can forward messages to instances of a class using `-forwardInvocation:`. Can I do the same for messages sent to a class object (as in `+forwardInvocation:`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can.

Comment: how... did you do that.